# How do I remove all items in a dictionary with a value less than a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of words and values, like:

```
{"word1" : 5, "word2" : 3, "word3", : 15, "word4" : 12}
```

I want to find and remove all the words that have a value less than 10, so it ends up like:

```
{"word3" : 15, "word4" : 12}
```

How do I do this? Just to say, I don't know the values in advance, so I can't just sort and trim some of it.

Comment: Nitpick: This is a dict of words and values, not a list. But dict comprehension is your friend, as Rakesh pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dict comprehension

**Ex:**

```
data = {"word1" : 5, "word2" : 3, "word3" : 15, "word4" : 12}
print({k:v for k, v in data.items() if v > 10})
```

**Output:**

```
{'word3': 15, 'word4': 12}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
mydict = {"word1" : 5, "word2" : 3, "word3", : 15, "word4" : 12}
for key in list(mydict):
  if mydict[key] < 10:
    del mydict[key]
```